# Google Mini frequently times out

Tags: google-search-appliance

I have a Google Mini device that I've successfully configured to index two websites on our network.

The problem is that about 50% of the time I load the admin site
http://192.168.0.150:8000 (our internal IP for the box)
I get the "Unable to connect" message as if the server was down.

Also, sometimes while I'm using the admin site I'll open the main search in a new tab (192.168.0.150) and then when I return to the admin it no longer works.

The usual fix is to close all browsers and try again.

This issue occurs on FF3, IE8 and Chrome.

I reviewed the network settings and confirmed they look OK to me (no errors on the diagnostics). I don't really know what else to troubleshoot. Are there patches I'm not aware of? Has anyone else seen this issue?

Any troubleshooting ideas?

j

Comment: That almost sounds like general IE8 breakage, does it apply to any browser or just IE?

Comment: FF, IE and Chrome.

Comment: Do a ping -t and let it go for awhile. If you get drops you'll know if it's a network issue rather then a higher level application issue

Comment: No drops during a long ping session. Not a network issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I'm a complete idiot.

The device was set with the same internal IP as another device on my network.

Comment: We've all made this mistake once.